# Pass a partial as a variable

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is it possible to pass a partial as a variable to another partial?
Something like:

```
{{>
template1
image="images/image1.jpg"
content=template2
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you are asking, then I think your question is answered in the Handlebars documentation on [Dynamic Partials](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html#dynamic-partials):

> If a simple variable has the partial name, it's possible to resolve it via the lookup helper.

Your template would have to call `template1` and pass they dynamic partial name as a string:

```
{{> template1 content="template2"}}
```

Your `template1` partial would have to include the following:

```
{{> (lookup . "content")}}
```

Comment: great, this looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Will try now

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass it as a string

```
{{> template1 tempPartial="template2"}}
```

And then reference it with

```
{{> (tempPartial) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, not quite sure what you mean though...passing a string just renders the string inside the first template

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, but it won't compile with the (). If I remove brackets it can't find the template