# Partial as partial parameter in Handlebars

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I was hoping that a partial could be used as the parameter to another partial... and inner partial also use params, within Handlebars.

```
{{>section-container
  classes="bg-class"
  contents=(>signup-banner form-present=true)
}}
```

Imagine I might be stuck with something like this with a [partial helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-helper-partial), but parse the string data param, yuck...

```
{{>section-container
  classes="bg-class"
  contents=(partial 'signup-banner' '{"form-present":true}')
}}
```

*(This is somewhat related: [Pass a partial as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301283/pass-a-partial-as-a-variable))*